# Searching local CSV data in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, csv, papaparse

I have a page in a React App that displays data stored in a local CSV file in a table and I want to add a search functionality that allows users to search through that data. I've tried a few tutorials but I'm new to this and I'm finding it really hard to understand.

the code for my page looks like this:

```
export default function Archive () {
    const [parsedCsvData, setParsedCsvData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            const response = await fetch("./RentFlagDB.csv");
            const reader = response.body.getReader();
            const result = await reader.read(); // raw array
            const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
            const csv = decoder.decode(result.value); // the csv text
            const results = Papa.parse(csv, { header: true, }); // object with { data, errors, meta }
            const rows = results.data; // array of objects
            setParsedCsvData(rows);
        }
        getData();
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="Archive">
            <table className="ArchiveTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr className='ArchiveTable'>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Postcode</th>
                        <th>Issue</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Score</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody className='ArchiveTable'>
                    {parsedCsvData &&
                        parsedCsvData.map((parsedData, index) => (
                            <tr key={index} className='ArchiveTable'>
                                <td>{parsedData.Name}</td>
                                <td>{parsedData.Address}</td>
                                <td>{parsedData.Postcode}</td>
                                <td>{parsedData.Issue}</td>
                                <td>{parsedData.Date}</td>
                                <td>{parsedData.Score}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This at least returns the search bar that I'm after but I've so far been unable to add any functionality to it at all.

```
const CsvSearch = ({ searchQuery, setSearchQuery }) => (
    <form action="/" method="get">
        <label htmlFor="header-search">

        </label>
        <input
            value={searchQuery}
            onInput={e => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            id="header-search"
            placeholder="Search the archive..."
            name="Searchbar"
        />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
);


export default CsvSearch;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to create this feature:

**Step #1: Read Excel Data**
There all lots of ways to do this, but I use [read-excel-file](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file) package, which supports CSV, XLSX, ... and it can create a structured array by JSON (mapping) or passing a schema option to its function:

```
const map = {
  // Column 1 same as Excel Column header Name
    'Column 1': 'columnNumberOne', // these are your Excel Columns that are going to turn into a clear Array
    'Column 2': 'columnNumberTwo',
    'Column 3': 'columnNumberThree',
    'Column 4': 'columnNumberFour',
    ...
  }
useEffect(() => {
  readXlsxFile(file, { map }).then(({ rows }) => { // file is your local excel file that you have to have it in every ways
    setParsedCsvData(rows.map((row, index) => ({ ...row, excelRow: index })));
  });
} , [])
```

**Step #2: Search, Filter, Select, Delete, ... in table**
I suggest you use [Material Table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started) in your first presentation, it really easy to learn with a good documentation

```
// fields are your csv Array keys
// titles are your table column desire name
<div style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}>
  <MaterialTable
    columns={[
      { title: 'Table Column 1 Header', field: 'columnNumberOne' },
      { title: 'Table Column 2 Header', field: 'columnNumberTwo' },
      { title: 'Table Column 3 Header', field: 'columnNumberThree' },
      { title: 'Table Column 4 Header', field: 'columnNumberFour' } }
    ]}
    data={parsedCsvData}
    title="Excel Table"
  />
</div>
```